# Posting an API to my database, JSON won't load

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know if the title is worded correctly but I currently have an object built, of which I know is built correctly as I can `console.log` it and It has everything I need right after the `POST` is done, however when i got to the api page such as `localhost:8080/api/orders`, it just shows up as an empty array.

Some information to go on, I currently have an array of objects being build by the user interface.  Basically when a user selects something it is automatically added to this array with properties `name`, `quantity`, and `tableNumber`.  Once this array of objects is built, I intend to post it to my database but when i got to the page it just shows me an empty array.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let tableNum = 1;
    var tableOneOrder = [];
    var chefTable = [];
    tableOneOrder.forEach(function (element) { element.quantity = "0"; });
    $('#submitForm').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault;

        $.ajax('/api/orders/',{
            method: 'PUT',
            data: chefTable
        }).then(function(){
            console.log(chefTable[chefTable.length-1]);
           // location.reload();
        });
    });
```

Comment: so like one page is fetching from the objects and putting to the database and other  page  `/api/orders/` is viewing you the results by fetching from database, am i right?

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is a function.

Comment: Work through the problem step-by-step.  Did the PUT fail (check console).  Did the server side succeed in processing the message?

Comment: I'm not showing the rest of the code because the page is too long but basically what is happening is the chefTable array already has the object I need to send via the other functions so in the ajax method, I know chefTable already has the info I need.  But when i supposedly send it to /api/orders, the only thing that appears is [].